# How to use sub-query in U-SQL?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am using U-SQL to get offset of date according to range(offset, startdate and enddate is available in another set).

I have tried using sub query but it throws error.

```
@partnerships =
    EXTRACT name string,
            createdon DateTime?,
            address1_stateorprovince string
    FROM "/Data/Partnerships"
    USING Extractors.Text(skipFirstNRows : 1, silent : true, quoting : false, delimiter : '\u0001');

@timeZones =
    EXTRACT Year int,
            DateFrom DateTime,
            DateTo DateTime,
            Offset int
    FROM "/Data/ESTTimeZones.csv"
    USING Extractors.Text(skipFirstNRows : 1, silent : true, quoting : false, delimiter : '\u0001');

@output =
    SELECT P.createdon,
           Convert.ToDateTime(P.createdon).AddHours(SELECT Offset from @timeZones  WHERE P.createdon >= T.DateFrom AND P.createdon <= T.DateTo) AS CreatedOn,
           T.Offset AS Offset
    FROM @partnerships AS P;

OUTPUT @output
TO "/Data/PartnershipwithOffset"
USING Outputters.Text(outputHeader : true, quoting : false, delimiter : '\u0001');
```

I am having two files one is `Partnerships` which contains `createdon` date and another file is `ESTTimeZones`, which contains `DateFrom` and `DateTo` with their offset. I want to find offset where `createdon` date lies beetween `DateFrom` and `DateTo`.

And add that `offset` in `createdOn` date and again convert that `createdon` date to `datetimeoffset` with particular offset using U-SQL.

I tried to find and add offset of particular `createdon` date. But I am getting a syntax error near `SELECT Offset` (because may be sub-query is not available in U-SQL).

So, is there any option available to get my requirement or any changes required from above approach.

Comment: Some sample data and expected results please.

Comment: Partnership table :                                                                                             
name | createdon           
John | 8/12/18 1:56 PM|
Doe | 02/7/17 10:00 AM|                                                                                      
timezone Table: DateFrom | DateTo| Offset|
11/7/2016 | 3/11/2017 | -5|
3/12/2017 | 11/5/2017 | -4|
11/6/2017 | 3/10/2018 | -5|
3/11/2018|11/4/2018|-4|
Expected results:name | createdon | offset |
John | 8/12/18 9:56 AM | -4|
Doe |  02/7/17 5:00 AM | -5|

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` your rowsets rather than using a sub select as you currently are.  You should always try to find a set based approach rather than applying some logic to each and every row.  Because U-SQL only supports equality comparisons in the `JOIN`, you need to build up your dataset to include all days between your `DateFrom` and `DateTo` values and provide a `Date` only version of your `createdon` value for the `JOIN`:

```
@partnerships =
    EXTRACT name string,
            createdon DateTime?,
            address1_stateorprovince string
    FROM "/Data/Partnerships"
    USING Extractors.Text(skipFirstNRows : 1, silent : true, quoting : false, delimiter : '\u0001');

@partnerships =
    SELECT name,
           (DateTime)createdon,
           ((DateTime)createdon).Date AS createdonDate,    // Just the date portion for the JOIN later on
           address1_stateorprovince
    FROM partnerships
    WHERE createdon IS NOT NULL;    // I have assumed this filter is necessary given your nullable input data.

@timeZones =
    EXTRACT Year int,
            DateFrom DateTime,
            DateTo DateTime,
            Offset int
    FROM "/Data/ESTTimeZones.csv"
    USING Extractors.Text(skipFirstNRows : 1, silent : true, quoting : false, delimiter : '\u0001');

@timeZones =
    SELECT Year,
           DateFrom,
           DateTo,
           ((int)(DateTo - DateFrom).TotalDays)) + 1 AS Days,    // Returns the total number of days covered by your date range
           Offset
    FROM @timeZones;

@timeZonesDays =
    SELECT t.Year,
           t.DateFrom,
           t.DateTo,
           t.Offset,
           d.JoinDate
    FROM @timeZones AS t
        CROSS APPLY EXPLODE(Enumerable.Range(0,t.Days)          // Creates a row for each day between each date range
                            .Select(n => t.DateFrom.AddDays(n))
                           ) AS d(JoinDate);

@output =
    SELECT p.createdon,
           p.createdon.AddHours(Offset) AS CreatedOn,
           t.Offset AS Offset
    FROM @partnerships AS p
        JOIN @timeZonesDays AS t
            ON p.createdonDate == t.JoinDate;

OUTPUT @output
TO "/Data/PartnershipwithOffset"
USING Outputters.Text(outputHeader : true, quoting : false, delimiter : '\u0001');
```

Comment: Both timeZonesDays and output returning blank result.

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug?